# covert below string to simple text

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
var arr2 ='{s:10:\"product_id\";s:11:\"11762430743\";s:13:\"product_price\";i:50;s:12:\"product_name\";s:68:\"Mercedes-AMG GT S 2016 In detail review walkaround Interior Exterior\";s:12:\"channel_name\";s:8:\"goplh114\";s:1:\"v\";s:11:\"Y1WzBFJFit8\";}';
```

How to get above JSON result like below:

```
product_id:11762430743
product_price:50
product_name: Mercedes-AMG GT S 2016 In detail review walkaround Interior Exterior
channel_name: goph114
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Use [`JSON.parse("your string")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

BTW. Your JSON string does not seams to be correcly formatted. You might want to check that out. https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: This is not a json, a valid json object looks like that  `{"key1":"test", "key2": ["test1", "test2"], "key3": { "sub-key1": "sub-test-1"}}`

Comment: i have no idea what kind of string you got there but it is certainly not JSON.